# Token check not working in custom component admin

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, administrator, security, security-token

I've built a custom component and have three forms that executes different tasks in the default.php view on subcontrollers within the administrator. Within my tmpl view `default.php`, each form has a `<?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>` which renders a hidden field with a token as the name with a value of 1. I have a check in my subcontroller, `JSession::checkToken() or die` to determine if the token is valid.

The issue is that when submitting a form via POST, the POST data with the token and the function `JSession::checkToken()` that checks the token are not a match thus results in `FALSE`. After debugging the JSession class, I found that when it gets a token, it is NOT the same as the token being posted. I've searched Google but could find any solution that worked.

According to [Joomla's documentation on CSRF](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_CSRF_anti-spoofing_to_forms), it's supposed to be as easy as adding `<?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>` and adding the check in the controller `JSession::checkToken() or die`.

How can the two tokens differ from the form POST and JSession class? Is there something else I maybe missing or have not added that is not in the Joomla doc?

Comment: It should work the way you did it. The tokens shouldn't differ as long as the session is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things occur to me:

Are you sure you're submitting to a "site" controller, and not an    "admin" controller? The token for a site vs. admin form will be    different, since the session is different.

Are you sure you're    submitting via `POST`? If you are submitting via `GET` you need to    check the token using `JSession::checkToken('get')`

Are you sure    that you have put the token field inside the form tags? You can view    the source to confirm that this all looks correct.

Comment: Thanks for the first tip. It was validating the frontend token so that's why the check was failing.